# passing library argument to gcc

Tags: linux, gcc

I've a shell on a system without root privileges. I am trying to use a custom library for my new project and it cannot be installed onto the system because I don't have the root privilege. I'm building the library from source. Making the '.o' from the sources has been done. I've tried passing the '.o' file, generated after building the source, as the library argument (-l) to gcc , but gcc says file not found. Any possible workarounds for this?

Comment: Come to think of it, the result of building a library is a .a file or a .so file, not a .o file.

Comment: Strange then, this lib produces a .o file

Comment: In which case, Spudd86 is correct, but that is not the normal case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass the .o as an extra bit just like the rest of your program.

`gcc <library.o> <yourprogram.o> -o <executable>`

Answer (score 1):

```
gcc -L/path/to/library/directory
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/library/directory:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH ./a.out
```